# org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineException: Error inside systemOut parser

Tags: maven, mule

I am running a maven build for my mule application and it is completing without any test failures.

```
===================================================================================
Number of tests run: 1 - Failed: 0 - Errors: 0 - Skipped: 0 - Time elapsed: 1.879ms
===================================================================================
[org.mule.munit.remote.CoverageManager]Calculating application coverage for resources: api.xml
```

But it looks like when it gets to calculating application coverages I get a ..

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ DevKit Extensions (1) used in this application                               +
+ ObjectStore 2.1.0 (DevKit 3.9.0 Build UNNAMED.2793.f49b6c7)+                 +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineException: Error inside systemOut parser
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineUtils$1.call(CommandLineUtils.java:308)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:164)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.CommandLineUtils.executeCommandLine(CommandLineUtils.java:99)
    at org.mule.runner.JVMStarter.execute(JVMStarter.java:58)
    at org.mule.MUnitMojo.doExecute(MUnitMojo.java:154)
    at org.mule.MUnitMojo.execute(MUnitMojo.java:123)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 349
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:176)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
    at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
    at org.mule.runner.model.RunResult.setCoverageReport(RunResult.java:174)
    at org.mule.runner.RunnerStreamConsumer.handleProtocolLine(RunnerStreamConsumer.java:93)
    at org.mule.runner.RunnerStreamConsumer.consumeLine(RunnerStreamConsumer.java:40)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.StreamPumper.consumeLine(StreamPumper.java:160)
    at org.apache.maven.shared.utils.cli.StreamPumper.run(StreamPumper.java:95)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 349
    at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.nextString(JsonReader.java:821)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:358)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.read(TypeAdapters.java:346)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.read(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:40)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:81)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:93)
    at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
    ... 19 more
```

I'm not sure what maven is doing? Any tips on how to resolve?

Comment: could you share the POJO for the file which you getting the `JsonSyntaxException` please

Comment: Hi, I've updated with the full stack. I don't think it's an exception in my code. I think it's something that maybe mule/maven is doing implicitly.

Comment: Any one, found a solution for this. I am facing this now

Answer (score 0):

Can you try by deleting the .mule folder from your workspace? Make sure you close AnyPoint Studio and then delete the aforementioned folder.

Comment: That did not work. But I'm thinking your on the right track. Something to do with my workspace or project settings.